# Is there a fast way to paste standard replies from Google Drive to Gmail?

Tags: gmail, google-drive

At the company where I work, our main email gets tons of standard email, and we usually have a set of standard replies stored in Google Docs. We usually copy paste from there.

Is there a way to do this faster? (Right click context menu etc?) For example, a Chrome extension.

I can move all standard replies to another service (for example, Dropbox Paper etc.), if they can provide similar functionality.

Standard Gmail Lab Canned Response does not work since we have many standard replies.

Comment: I use about 10 canned replies, and apart from a sucky menu (insert, edit, delete) why are you saying it's too many?

Comment: Streak bas that, e!ven in the free version